# Does a BroadcastReceiver get unregistered when the app reinstalls even if unregisterReceiver is not used?

Tags: android

I have an app that has a dialog that asks users if they want to install a new update if there is one. I have BroadcastReceivers registered inside the dialog class to receive broadcasts regarding download progress etc.

When the download finishes, the app closes and goes into the install screen for the newly downloaded apk.

In that case, would I still have to unregister the BroadcastReceiver or would a new install automatically unregister all BroadcastReceivers?

Comment: Your process will be terminated when the update is applied, and that will remove all dynamically-registered receivers (set up via `registerReceiver()`).

Comment: @CommonsWare When you say "process will be terminated", do you mean the `registerReceiver()` will be terminated? So as long as I'm sure the app would be reinstalled, it wouldn't cause any leaks due to not unregistering the receiver?

Comment: No, I mean the process will be terminated. "it wouldn't cause any leaks due to not unregistering the receiver?" -- when your process is terminated, all of its memory is released back to the OS, including those of any `BroadcastReceiver` objects.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks!